# Bind problems Debian

Tags: bind

```
root@alexx8761:~# named-checkconf -z
zone j-buy.ru/IN: loaded serial 2013052601
zone 8.16.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2013052601
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
root@alexx8761:~# rndc reload
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe formating the error message could help other to interpret it better.
From the error message, you have an error in another file

> failed: unbalanced parentheses dns_master_load: /etc/bind/8.16.172.in-addr.arpa.zone:11: unbalanced parentheses

Try to solve the parentheses issue in file /etc/bind/8.16.172.in-addr.arpa.zone

And you have also this error

> file does not end with newline